# Play! Java. pass request param to @With anotation

Tags: java, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.2

I have routes like:

```
  GET     /job$id<[0-9]+>/        controllers.Jobs.index(id)
  POST    /job$id<[0-9]+>/done    controllers.Jobs.done(id)
  POST    /job$id<[0-9]+>/update  controllers.Jobs.update(id)
  DELETE  /job$id<[0-9]+>/remove  controllers.Jobs.remove(id)
```

and I' like to secure it. Each job has an owner. So I made

```
public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {
...
}
```

Then I tryed to secure all my Actions by "**@With()**" annotatian, but I need to pass "**Id**" param to my secure method, so I wrote smth like:

```
@With(IsOwner.class)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Owner {
    long value() default 0;
}

public static class IsOwner extends Action<Owner>{
    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {

        if(!isOwner(configuration.value())){
            return Promise.pure(redirect(..));
        }
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

But I can't pass my action parametr to annotation.

```
@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)

@Owner(id) //**this part I want to work**
public class Jobs extends Controller {

  //@Owner(id) - or at list there
  public static Result index(Long Id){
    //I have too many Actions and don't want to do every time this
    /*if(!Secured.isOwnerMethod(Id)){
      return forbidden();
    }*/         
    return ok();        
  }
```

Other way I see is get params from **Context** in **IsOwner.call()** method...

Please, give me a recommendation or good practise for such situations.

Thanks.

Comment: Well.. annotation variables can be only constants. So I need the way to get my path param at call() method.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and came up with a Play extension that exposes all url parameters as common request parameters... You can check it out here => https://github.com/asouza/reverse-route-plugin

Basically you have to extend from my Global class.

Cheers,

Alberto

Comment: Thanks. But I dont think it's a best way to do it.

Comment: Probably it is not... But there is no other way, at least for now :).